# How do I make a jqgrid display inline adjacent to another jqgrid or just a div?

Tags: css, jqgrid, inline

Using css display inline on the 2 divs that contain the grids does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

specify a width for your divs and use "float: left" or "right" as per your requirement. Don't use "inline" for divs

eg CSS :

```
div {
 width: 100px;
 float: left;
}
```